# How to iterate over array of objects to add counter value if duplicate names are found in objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have 1 array of object and want to iterate over the objects in it. So if duplicate name entries are found i have to add counter values and it should be merged. Final array of object must have unique entries.

ObjectA =

```
[
  {name: 'Voice', counter: 1},
  {name: 'tele', counter: 1},
  {name: 'equip', counter: 1},
  {name: 'equip', counter: 2},
  {name: 'Voice', counter: 1}
]
```

Result should be:-

ObjectB =

```
[
  {name: 'Voice', counter: 2},
  {name: 'tele', counter: 1},
  {name: 'equip', counter: 3}
]
```

Comment: please add your code. please look here, too: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** with some logic as follows.

**`DEMO`**

```js
let data = [{name: 'Voice', counter: 1},
           {name: 'tele', counter: 1},
           {name: 'equip', counter: 1},
           {name: 'equip', counter: 2},
           {name: 'Voice', counter: 1}]


var result = [];
data.reduce(function (res, value) {
    if (!res[value.name]) {
        res[value.name] = {        
        name: value.name,
        counter: 0
        };
        result.push(res[value.name])
    }
    res[value.name].counter += value.counter
    return res;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and sum all `counter` values, grouped by `name`.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'Voice', counter: 1 }, { name: 'tele', counter: 1 }, { name: 'equip', counter: 1 }, { name: 'equip', counter: 2 }, { name: 'Voice', counter: 1 }],
    unique = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { name, counter }) => m.set(name, (m.get(name) || 0) + counter), new Map),
        ([name, counter]) => ({ name, counter })
    );

console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'Voice', counter: 1},
  {name: 'tele', counter: 1},
  {name: 'equip', counter: 1},
  {name: 'equip', counter: 2},
  {name: 'Voice', counter: 1}
];

const resultObj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.name] = (acc[item.name] || 0) + item.counter;
  return acc;
}, {})

const resultArr = Object.entries(resultObj).map(entry => ({
  name: entry[0],
  counter: entry[1]
}))

document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(resultArr, null, 2)}</pre>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to group the objects having same `name` from the list. Later if the object having the same name is found the `counter` is increased, else the object is pushed into the array.

```js
var arr = [{name: 'Voice', counter: 1},
           {name: 'tele', counter: 1},
           {name: 'equip', counter: 1},
           {name: 'equip', counter: 2},
           {name: 'Voice', counter: 1}];

var newArray = arr.reduce((acc, item)=>{
var element = acc.find(obj => obj['name'] === item['name']);
if(element){
   element['counter'] = element['counter'] + 1;
 }else{
  acc.push(item);
 }
return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can use lodash reduce function*

```js
    let data = [{name: 'Voice', counter: 1},
               {name: 'tele', counter: 1},
               {name: 'equip', counter: 1},
               {name: 'equip', counter: 2},
               {name: 'Voice', counter: 1}];
    
    data = _.reduce(data, (arr, n)=> {
        const index = _.findIndex(arr,{name: n.name});
        if(index !== -1){
          arr[index].counter += 1; 
        } else {
          arr.push(n);
        }
        return arr;
        },[]);
      
      console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```